# Behaviour of ext3 filesystem when it hits %100

Tags: linux, ext3

We had an unexpected increase on one of our mount points (~40GB)  on a old RHEL 4 server (2.6.9-89.0.2 x86_64 kernel). It hit %100 usage ( Size and Used both said 37G, Avail said 0) as per df -h.

I found a directory that appeared to unused (some old backup software that we don't use at all). lsof had no record of it at all (including lsof | grep deleted). It was about 200 MB. I moved it to another disk partition with space available (and used sym link to point back to it.) It didn't reclaim any space. I ran sync; sync. Are my expectations off?

Comment: What caused the increase in usage? Just speculating, but depending on the cause of the unexpected usage, those 200MB might have been ocupied as soon as they were freed.

Comment: What do you mean by "I moved it to another mount point with a symlink"? Did you move the file to a differnet subtree and then symlink to it so as to preserve its original path? Also, use a more granular output from `df`, such as `df -BM`, as you're not making a difference of 1 GiB.

Comment: Edited to clarify mv. Unfortunately I only used df - h.